# Template vs type casting

Tags: c++, templates, casting, type-conversion

I have this vector class based on float that I use to store the coorinates of my objects and when i need them as an int I would simply do type casting.
But sometimes i find myself in a situation where i'm not in need of float at all and I could use the same class but based on integer.
So should i use  a template on this class or should i let it be float based?

```
#pragma once
class Vec2
{
public:
    Vec2(float x, float y);
public:
    bool operator==(Vec2& rhs);
    Vec2 operator+(Vec2& rhs) const;
    Vec2 operator*(float rhs) const;
    Vec2 operator-(Vec2& rhs) const;
    Vec2& operator+=(Vec2& rhs);
    Vec2& operator-=(Vec2& rhs);
    Vec2& operator*=(float rhs);
    float LenghtSqrt() const;
    float Lenght() const;
    float Distance(const Vec2& rhs) const;
    Vec2 GetNormalized() const;
    Vec2& Normalize();
public:
    float x, y;

};
```

Comment: You could provide a default template arg of `float` and then `typedef Vec2<> Vec2`, you could also give `Vec2` a generic name to use with non default template types.

Answer (score 2):

> i'm not in need of float at all and I could use the same class but based on integer

Yes, making `Vec2` a class template is appropriate here. This would allow you to parametrize the class on any numerical type, while avoiding duplication of your interface and logic.

```
template <typename T>
class Vec2
{
public:
    Vec2(T x, T y);
public:
    bool operator==(Vec2& rhs);
    Vec2 operator+(Vec2& rhs) const;
    Vec2 operator*(T rhs) const;
    Vec2 operator-(Vec2& rhs) const;
    Vec2& operator+=(Vec2& rhs);
    Vec2& operator-=(Vec2& rhs);
    Vec2& operator*=(T rhs);
    float LenghtSqrt() const;
    float Lenght() const;
    float Distance(const Vec2& rhs) const;
    Vec2 GetNormalized() const;
    Vec2& Normalize();
public:
    T x, y;
};
```